# arguments are not passed to command line utlity from batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i am trying to pass some commands/arguments from a batch file to a command line utility cmda.exe but on running the batch file it just open the cmd window but does not execute any command written ahead of it.

these are the lines written in my batch file

```
D:
cmda.exe
atprogram
atprogram -t avrone -i pdi -d atxmega128a1 chiperase
```

Comment: is `atprogram` an exe or a batch file?

Comment: You do not pass any arguments to `cmda.exe`. Everything in a new line is not an argument any more, it's a new command

Comment: yes atprogram is a command in atmel command line utility which shows help related to all other commands that will be used in programming

Comment: last line is a command to erase controller chip. but none of them is executed

Comment: again: is `atprogram` an exe or a batch file? `yes` may be technically correct, but doesn't help.

Comment: atprogram is a command not an exe or batch file.

Comment: Wild guess: cmda.exe opens a new console and the batch waits for it's termination to then continue executing atprogramm ....

Comment: yes you are right. but i need to open cmda.exe to program my chip. any thing that can be done to transfer commands to this new console.

Comment: it will probably be a single line, if cmda.exe excepts external commands with parameters. something like `d:\cmda.exe atprogram -t avrone -i pdi -d atxmega128a1 chiperase`

Comment: still not working

Comment: I do not have cmda.exe so not able to test myself. how do you run cmda.exe with commands manually usualy?

Comment: what exact paths are the files cmda.exe and atprogram.exe?

Comment: yes write manual commands in cmda.exe

Comment: atprogram is a command not .exe

Comment: cmda.exe is command line utility for programming atmel controllers. atprogram is a command just like "dir" or "cd" etc

Comment: original application name was Atmel Studio Command Prompt.exe which i renamed to cmda.exe.